# Hero card in bot framework without an aciton

Tags: botframework

Is there an option to create a hero card (or any other type of card) with no action? According to documentation there should be at least one action or more.

When trying to set the actions list to an empty list it did work on skype and telegram but in FB I did not return any response.

Comment: I've confirmed that this is and issue.  Investigating.

Comment: Please mark Lars' answer as correct so this old question doesn't show up as unresolved in the side bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for identifying this bug.  It has been fixed and will be published in our next deployment.